# How do I call unmanaged C/C++ code from a C# ASP.NET webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, c++, dll, unmanaged

I have an ASP.NET website that uses C# and I'd like to call functions from an unmanaged C/C++ DLL. How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out P/Invoke.

[Calling Win32 DLLs in C# with P/Invoke](http://web.archive.org/web/20110616075559/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104(v=vs.71).aspx)

If it's a COM dll, then you can use [COM Interop](http://web.archive.org/web/20090220152731/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 10):

1. create an unmanaged dll:

   ```
   extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl int sum(int a,int b); ---->
   ```
2. create a namespace/class to DllImport the above DLL

   ```
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
   namespace ImportDLL
   {
   public class importdll
   {
   public importdll()
   {
   }

   DllImport("mysum.dll",
             EntryPoint="sum",
             ExactSpelling=false,
             CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
   public extern int myfun(int a, int b);
   }
   }
   ```
3. create a aspx code behind

   ```
   using ImportDLL;
   namespace TEST
   {
    public int my_result;
    protected importdll imp = new importdll();
    my_result = imp.myfun(1,1);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding that [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) is a great wiki/resource for your Win32 needs.