# Calling C dll code from C#?

Tags: c#, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I call unmanaged C/C++ code from a C# ASP.NET webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720004/how-do-i-call-unmanaged-c-c-code-from-a-c-asp-net-webpage)

is there a way to link the two?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720004/how-do-i-call-unmanaged-c-c-code-from-a-c-asp-net-webpage

Comment: many examples Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework(http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3574)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx) is the approach you want

Answer (score 2):

Search for **PInvoke** in C#
you will find plenty of resources. Like this one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, PInvoke is the way. [This site/wiki](http://pinvoke.net/) will be a great help likely.